# Can't connect the library to react-native 042 + type script

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, import, lib

Have a simple project on react native 0.42.0 and type script 2.3.2. After installing the library https://github.com/leecade/react-native-swiper and adding typing www.npmjs.com/package/@types/react-native-swiper. When you try to connect the library, by the way

> import * as Swiper from 'react-native-swiper'

as specified in typescript documentation. I have error in the application com.facebook.react.common.JavascriptException: {"stack":"Error: Failed to execute 'importScripts' on 'WorkerGlobalScope': The script at 'http://localhost:8081/index.android.bundle?.
Also I tried to connect

> const Swiper = require('react-native-swiper');
>
> import Swiper from 'react-native-swiper'

ts compiled normally but react native can not run the attached and send the same error.
I can not understand how to connect that would work?? HELP!! A lot of time waste on the plain task ((

Comment: Pretty sure you had `Debug JS remotely` enabled. Try disabling it and your error log should change.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I realized my mistake. It named project folder like "RN042_TS". When I rebuild project in a different name folder "testReactNative" and change the project name in packaje.json - all started work fine. Start work usually import.